# Colorate the column header which the filter is activated

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel, I have not found a solution in VBA (macro) that allows me to colorate the column header which the filter is activated.
I am looking for a solution that will help me to see columns whose filters are enabled, by the header color of the selected column.
That solution will be very useful when we work on a table with several columns.

Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: Have you tried something so far? where is your code? And did you mean "color the column header when filter is activated"?

Comment: Also please look at the brief tour on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: To give you a start, you should look at the following `Worksheet` properties/methods: `AutoFilterMode`, `FilterMode`, `AutoFilter.Filters.Count`, `AutoFilter.Filters(...).On` (and in that order ;-) )

Comment: You can use the Autofilter.Range.Address to get the range of the filter acting on.  Then look at the filters, 1 to how many you have and look at each On property, then if say filter 3 is on, column 3 of your range is filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your idea,
I have found a solution, exactly what I want! :)
The solution is to insert the following VBA code in "ThisWorkbook" :

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Integer
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ActiveSheet
With Ws
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        With .AutoFilter.Filters
            For x = 1 To .Count
                If .Item(x).On Then Ws.Cells(1, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            Next
        End With
    End If
End With
End Sub